# Aplicar marcador en Mapbox a partir de un nivel de zoom

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapbox

Estamos creando un mapa con Mapbox y necesitamos saber si se puede hacer que los marcadores aparezcan a partir de cierto nivel, como por ejemplo 13 o 14.

El código con el que cargamos los marcadores y dibujamos el mapa es este:

```
const setMap = ( map: Map ) => {
        const {expedientes} = Entregas
        
        const myLocationPopup = new Popup()
            .setHTML(`
            <h4>Bienvenidos a LIS</h4>
            <p>Te AIudamos</p>
        `);

        new Marker()
            .setLngLat( map.getCenter() )
            .setPopup( myLocationPopup )
            .addTo( map );

            
            norepobj(expedientes).map((exp:any) => {
                
                const popup = new Popup()
                    .setHTML(
                        `<h3>${exp.exp_direccion}</h3>
                        <p>${exp.exp_ent_conjunta}</p>`
                    );
        
            
            new Marker()
                .setPopup( popup )
                .setLngLat([ parseFloat(exp.exp_longitud), parseFloat(exp.exp_latitud)])
                .addTo( map );
            })
            
            dispatch({ type: 'setMap', payload: map }) 
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitarían conseguir el zoom actual, puebren con algo así:

```js
 map.on('zoom', () => {
  map.getZoom();
 });
```

Luego usas ese zoom para crear tu condición. Espero les sirva.